# Размещение двух виджетов в строку android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Я хочу чтобы у меня два виджета: spinner и checkBox были размещены в одну строку. Я много перечитал здесь и на enSO вопросов и ответов и сделал такую разметку:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:entries="@array/filter_list" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

пришлось поменять у spinner параметр `android:layout_weight` с 1 на 0.1 потому что получалось что он был на пол экрана, а мне нужно было чтобы он занимал около 85% всей выделенной ширины layout. Но я не уверен что я правильно сделал, и решил спросить здесь мнение по поводу моего решения. Надеюсь что у меня не очень много ошибок получилось.

Comment: для таких задач лучше всего подходит ConstraintLayout, в котором к тому де не так давно появилась возможность указывать параметры сразу в процентах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно. Получится примерно 9%, а не 85%. И вообще лучше использовать целые числа (не уверен, что в `android:layout_weight` можно использовать десятичные).

- Считается так: складываем все `android:layout_weight`, которые имеются. Это 100%.
- Раздаем каждому элементу по его весу.

Т.о. для 85% при двух элементах нужно выделить 85% от общей суммы. Например, дать спиннеру `android:layout_weight="85"`, а чекбосу оставшиеся `android:layout_weight="15"`. Применив арифметику получим для спинера 17, а для чекбокса 3. Получится ровно 85% (3 = 85% от суммы 3 и 17).

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="17"
            android:entries="@array/filter_list" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

PS. Покурил [мануал](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_weight). В параметре `android:layout_weight` можно использовать и дробные числа.

> May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

Comment: Переменил параметры, а то случайно наоборот получилось.

Comment: вот если поменять значения `weight` у спиннера и у чекбокса, то все показывает так как нужно

Comment: Да, я там перепутал :) Поменял уже.

Comment: не нужно было менять)) у меня сейчас так как у вас было до изменений)) то есть к правому краю чек прижимается спиннером

Comment: Ну может быть. Я запутался кому сколько надо :) Но методика надеюсь понятна.

Comment: да я понял принцип спасибо :)

Comment: можно указывать значения прямо "в процентах", то есть использовать 85 и 15 без конвертации в доли или сокращения отношения, параметр сам высчитает соотношение. для облегчения расчетов контейнеру, который содержит вилжеты с весами, можно указать weightSum, в данном случае она будет 100.